# Protractor - Change css property to interact with element

Tags: javascript, protractor

Currently in the page I am testing I have a `select` that is with `display: none` in css, so I can not interact with this element. I searched but I did not find anything to help me.

**HTML**

```
<select name="preview_district" placeholder="Departamento" data-native-select="true" data-toggle-placeholder="true">
<option value="*" disabled="" selected="" hidden="">(Selecciona)</option>
<option value="91">AMAZONAS</option>
<option value="5">ANTIOQUIA</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
select[data-native-select="true"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to interact with this element if it's not supposed to be displayed to users?

Comment: @Gunderson just to select any option, Because above this `select` we are using several elements for the dropdown to be "pretty", So it's really complicated to select

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are automating an Angular page, so here we go.

First of all be sure that you can interact with the element when it is visible, you can do this from within the DevTools of your browser, make it visible by adding a `display:block`. Then check that if you change the value of the selectbox, the value can also be used with Angular Binding.

If so, you can easily make the element visible with Protractor by injecting a piece of Javascript in the page with the following command

```
browser.executeScript('document.querySelector(\'[name="preview_district"]\').style.display = "block"');
```

This results in a promise, so be aware of that!

You can also pass the protractor `ElementFinder`, it wil then look like this (use by.model / by.css / or something else)

```
browser.executeScript('arguments[0].style.display = "block"', element(by.css('.your-selector')).getWebElement());
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Through the name I am not able to make this attribute visible. No alternative is working. Any idea?

Comment: Depends on how the CSS is structured, I can't help with that because I don't have the CSS and HTML of the page